# Feet to Meters Conversion Loop - PHP

Tags: php, loops

I'm trying to convert feet to meters using a loop. It's supposed to go from 1 to the selected input number converting feet to meters.

Here's my code so far:

```
<html>
<body>
    <?php
    $feet=$_GET['feet'];
    for ($i=1; $i<$feet; $i++)
    {
        if ($meters=$feet * .3048) 
        {
            echo ( "$feet feet = $meters meters </br>" );
        }
    }

echo ( "</br> End Loop." );
?>
</body>
</html>
```

But instead of getting 1 to input number i get this (let's say i entered in 20)

```
 20 feet = 6.096 meters
 20 feet = 6.096 meters
 20 feet = 6.096 meters
 20 feet = 6.096 meters
 20 feet = 6.096 meters
....
```

when it's supposed to be

```
 1 feet = 0.305 meters
 2 feet = 0.610 meters
 3 feet = 0.914 meters
 ...
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

change

```
if ($meters=$feet * .3048)
```

to

```
if ($meters=$i * .3048)
```

and as jterry notes, you can get rid of the if statment, as your not really compairing anything.

Just do:

```
$meters = $feet * .3048;
echo ( "$i feet = $meters meters </br>" );
```

Comment: it doesn't really matter, to be fair he could get rid of the if statement completely as it'll always be true.

Comment: Thanks so much! I changed the $feet in the echo too and it worked.

Comment: if i wanted to change the output of "1 feet" to "1 foot" while leaving the rest of the ouput as "feet", how would i got about doing that also?

Comment: replace the word `foot` with `" . ($i === 1 ? "foot" : "feet") . "`

Comment: would that go in my for statement or somewhere in my if statement

Comment: nope, just in your echo, just remove the word feed for what i just wrote. give things a try, it wont blow up :)

Comment: i'm trying haha :) it's not working unfortunately. this right? "echo ( "$i " . ($i === 1 ? "foot" : "feet") . " = $meters meters </br>" );"

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
$meters = $i * .3048;
echo ( "$i feet = $meters meters </br>" );
```